# Why is (mono) asp.net slower than php?

Tags: php, asp.net, fastcgi, backend

I have a simple hello world written in asp.net, php and regular html. They are being served by nginx using fastcgi for php5 and xsp (mono 2.6.7, fastcgi-mono-server2.exe 2.6.5.0). I am using a simple .NET script to make async web request. What i found was in the span of 1000ms

- php: 250-400
- asp: 120-140
- html: 600-900
- 8k png: 250-300

With a simple hello world app php is consistently 2-3x faster.
Why is this? i always thought asp.net would be faster (and php startup would be slow). But it appears per request asp is significantly slower. Now i understand i am not actually comparing execution speed since its hello word and not complex code.

What is the difference between the two backends to make this significant difference?

[Here is the code i use to test the request](http://www.pastie.org/2609554).

Comment: You're trying to make *lots* of requests at the same time, in a pretty uncontrolled fashion. Now your client *may* be throttled by the number of requests it will issue to the same host at the same time - it depends how everything is configured... or it may be spamming the server with hundreds of requests at once. At that point, the behaviour will depend on how the server handles multiple connections. Note that your count increment is also not thread safe. Have you tried a *synchronous* fetch, so you're only making one request at a time, out of interest?

Comment: Jon Skeet: I was unsure how thread safety would work. All i know is its equally unsafe to each of them. What class might i use to increment the count in a thread safe manner? If you look at line 31 you can see i do have a version that handles one request at a time.

Comment: You could use `Interlocked.Increment` for example. What's the difference in performance when you use a synchronous approach? Note that if there's nothing dynamic in the page, it may well be that PHP is better at noticing that than ASP.NET, and is basically caching. As with all benchmarks, you have to ask whether it's really measuring the scenario which is relevant to the application you're interested in.

Comment: @Jon: I added the safe increment and played around with other things. I added code to detect caching and made php spit a unique id. Its speed is the same as it was before. I single and multithreaded numbers look the same. I think the async numbers went up after i added Interlocked but they look roughly the same (its hard to tell when each run varies a lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because fastcgi is not well implemented. I am using mono xsp web server, its recommended to use as dev server only but it works pretty good in production
[Here is Article](http://devimpress.com/archives/278) about performance tests 
Its in Russian but scroll down there is a table where you can take some information

Comment: That makes no sense. Php (i believe i am using php-fpm) is through fastcgi as well...

Comment: I gave you link to real test which shows that fastcgi in mono is not well done. Now i am hosting my project on ubuntu and just to confirm every day i had to restart fastcgi server  and it uses more CPU then nginx + xsp.

Comment: haha, i did notice that. However i don't need to restart my fastcgi mono

Comment: My VPS have only 1 gb of memory so maybe thats why i had that issues.

Comment: Mine was 256mb lol. I am using mono 2.6.7. Most of the memory is used by php-fpm, mysql, mono for 3 sites, mysql then php calling wordpress cron every min then finally 2 different single mono bots. Memory usage in that order.

Comment: You got me curious about xsp2, i wonder if i can still use nginx features such as `X-Accel-Redirect`

Comment: I am not sure but you can easy check it. As mono-xsp can be runned on other port. So you can create subdomain in NGINX then proxy path to xsp port and you can test it. Also dont forget to add machineKey to you web config because xsp will lost your session after each restart :)